# Generic Array Comparison in Java

Tags: java, generics

I had a small program using generic method for dealing with array in Java:

```
public class GenericMethodTest {
    // generic method                         
    public static <E> void inspectArray(E[] inputArray) {
        for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            int tmp = inputArray[i-1].compareTo(inputArray[i]);
            //unrelated lines are neglected                
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
        Integer[] intArray = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 2 };
        Character[] charArray = { 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A' };
        inspectArray( intArray  ); // pass an Integer array
        inspectArray( charArray ); // pass a Character array
    } 
}
```

However, I got an error message saying:

```
"The method compareTo(E) is undefined for the type E"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to ensure that `E` is `Comparable`. The correct method signature would be

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void inspectArray(E[] inputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the type `E` has a `compareTo` method, that is the contract of the interface `Comparable<T>`, then this could be written as:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void inspectArray( E[] inputArray) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: `E extends Comparable<E>`. Or, actually, what Elliott Frisch already got. :-P